# Tried Everying, Searched Everything, Issues installing Quantstrat package from Github

Tags: r, quantstrat

Installing Quantstrat Issues. I am running the latest versions of R, RStudio, and Rtools. I have installed devtools / remotes packages and cannot seem to get quantstrat installed. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy0jw.png)

Comment: You should detail everything you've already tried in order to fix this.

Comment: My apologies. I have read that I need to install Rtools which I have done already. I have tried to install quantstrat and blotter from Github using devtools package, but I'm getting the following error message: "Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 3.5.1 was found. (Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:3.5)"

Comment: When asked for additional information, please edit the information into the question itself. People who have downvoted you cannot retract their downvote if you haven't edited your post.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems too. Installing quantstrat via cmd works well for me. Here are the steps:

1. Create a folder for packages i.e RPackages\
2. Download the file from github to that specific folder and extract the files to the library name. i.e RPackages\quantstrat\
3. go on command line and goto RPackages
4. Type" `R CMD build quantstrat`
5. If it was successful, you will get a message like "building 'package_name_version_number.tar.gz'"
6. Now type: `R CMD INSTALL package_name_version_number.tar.gz`

Let me know if you have any other challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix that worked for me:

There could be version issues depending on what version of R that you have especially for Blotter and PerformanceAnalytics.  Since PerformanceAnalytics to install blotter, you must ensure that version force compatibility and the easiest way is just to install it fresh.  Start by installing PerformanceAnalytics then blotter then quantstrat and you should be in good shape.  Use the code below and let me know how your results turn out.  Took me a few hours to solve it, but just got it done today (7/27/2020)

install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")

remotes::install_github("braverock/blotter")

remotes::install_github("braverock/quantstrat", force = TRUE)