# Blotter cannot be loaded in r 3.5.1

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

I was able to use blotter and run quantstrat fine with previous r version 
However, I have updated R vesion to 3.5.1 and when I load blotter I receive this msg when loading blotter:

"Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘blotter’: package ‘blotter’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version"

I have tried reinstall all packages. but blotter still does not work. There are info about many different r packages that return same error after R 3.5. but I cannot find a solution to this one. and it does not seem liek anyone has posted similar question on stackoverflow.

Can anyone give me some tips

Thx!

Comment: There is much information missing here. What is your operating system? If windows, do you have Rtools-3.5 installed? Do you have all dependencies (and the minimum versions) loaded and confirmed working? What *exactly* happens (warning/error text) when you remove and then `install.packages("blotter")`?

Comment: `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)` maybe?

Comment: I do have  Rtools-3.5 installed, there is no blotter on cran I downloaded the the source code is dl from github.
once I switched back to r 3.4.4 version I have no problem installing both blotter and quantstrat.  That is the only thing I can work with for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same method I suggested for quantstrat package.

[Tried Everying, Searched Everything, Issues installing Quantstrat package from Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156034/tried-everying-searched-everything-issues-installing-quantstrat-package-from-g/52158022#52158022)

Let me know if it works.

Comment: thx @boniface316. I am not a developer so in you post when you say via cmd, you mean window cmd console right? I type in R CMD build quantstrat after get to the folder use cd command but the return error is:
"'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
I tried same command in r console and error is "Error: unexpected symbol in "R CMD"". 
really appreciate if you could clarify what is where I should input that cmd line. THX

Comment: No worries. First of all, I apologize for not being clear on "cmd". 

cmd is the command prompt (some call it console).

Can you goto cmd and type "R" and let me know if its working or not (It should open R not RStudio)?  If its giving you an error, then you have would have to install R all over again. 

What OS are you using? Win 7?